# ORA-00904: : invalid identifier error fix in oracle

Tags: oracle

this one works

```
create table reservation(
reservation_num number(6) constraint reservation_num_pk primary key,
rdate date,  
payment_status varchar(6) constraint payment_status_ck check(payment_status in('paid','unpaid')),
seat_num number(6),
flight_num number(3)
)
```

but this one fails

```
create table reservation(
reservation_num number(6) constraint reservation_num_pk primary key,
date date,  
payment_status varchar(6) constraint payment_status_ck check(payment_status in('paid','unpaid')),
seat_num number(6),
flight_num number(3)
)
```

Comment: Date is a reserved word.Instead use `reservation_date` or `booking_date` something meaningful

Comment: It's already been pointed out that the error stems from trying to use a reserved word as a column name.  I always avoid even the hint of that with my naming conventions - all column names are in the format 'adjective_noun'.  That not only avoid any chance of inadvertantly using a reserved word, it also makes names more descriptive - more self-documenting.  And you actually did that for all of the other column names.  So why not for that one 'date' column?

Answer (score 0):

Date is a reserved word. If you really want to use it as column name put it in double quotes

```
create table reservation(
reservation_num number(6) constraint 
reservation_num_pk primary key,
"date" date,  
payment_status varchar(6) constraint payment_status_ck 
check(payment_status in('paid','unpaid')),
seat_num number(6),
flight_num number(3)
 )
```

Comment: That will "work" in so much as it avoids the error and allows the table to be created, but it is horrible practice.  Once you enclose an object name in double quotes you forever make it case-sensitive and require double-quotes and the exact correct case every time you refer to it.

Comment: The next question from OP's colleague: *How to resolve `ORA-00936: missing expression` in `select date from reservation`*

Comment: @EdStevens I didn't say it's a good practice but it's the answer of the question.

Comment: @astentx Also include date in double quotes.